# jQuery - find number in text then append to another div

Tags: jquery, integer, append

I want to find number and append to a div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $numb = $('#my').html().match(/\d+/g);
    $numb.appendTo('#result');
});
```

for testing i add a alert, this work fine but append not working.
here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EQMz/1/)

what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `numb` is a numerical value, you need to use `.append()` to append it to the target element like

```
var numb = $('#my').html().match(/\d+/g)[0];
$('#result').append(numb);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q84qL/)

Comment: dude, i saw Fiddle, but still not working, 6 must append to red div.

Comment: @ITSolution it was because of a wrong update to it... see now

Comment: @ITSolution `.match()` returns an array, so you need to get the first value from it... the soulution is proper in the answer.. in the fiddle after that I made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

`$numb` is not jQuery Object it's just a simple variable which contains number .

you can't apply `appendTo()` with variables you need jQuery Object.

You need

`$('#my').html().match(/\d+/g)`  return array so you need to get the first value of the array  so change it to `$('#my').html().match(/\d+/g)[0]` . as index starts from `0` .

[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
var $numb = $('#my').html().match(/\d+/g)[0];
$('#result').append($numb);
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gHNQy/)</kbd>

Comment: did you test it? for me still not working in fiddle. 6 must append to red div.

Answer (score 0):

I might do it the other way round

```
var $numb = $('#my').html().match(/\d+/g);

$('#result').append($numb.toString());
```